# How can I increase space between lines within the text shown in the ASP.NET label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, label, spacing

I have a `label` in an `ASP.NET` `C#` application.

At `runtime`, the ASP.NET `label` value gets `populated` with text.

In the **ASPX** file, we have the following code:

```
<asp:Label ID="commentLabelForGridView" runat="server" 
      Style="text-align:left;" font-size="1.75em" ></asp:Label>
```

In the **code-behind CS** file, we have the following code:

```
commentLabelForGridView.Text = "BlahBlahBlah........Blah...................";
```

When there is a lot of text in the ASP label, the `text` that is rendered on the page becomes `Multilined`.

The problem is that there is not enough space between the lines so it is difficult to read because it looks congested.

How can be increase space between lines within the text shown in the ASP.NET label?

Comment: Style should have a line-height attribute you can set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user2025312 for mentioning that modifying the line-height attribute should help out.

Answer (score 1):

Add line-height attribute in Style...

```
<asp:Label ID="commentLabelForGridView" runat="server" 
      Style="text-align:left; line-height:1.5px" font-size="1.75em" ></asp:Label>
```

... it can be :
 line-height:1.5px or
 line-height:100%

hope it helps..